# using an asymptote for program completion

Tags: python, exit-code

This question could be answered in a language-agnostic fashion, but I am using python (fyi).

I am running an infinite loop which needs to terminate when during the last minute <10 new objects are discovered.

Eg:

```
while True:
    newobjs = dig_more_objects(obj)
    if less than 10 newobjs have been discovered over the last minute
        break
```

EDIT: The question is this: How do I implement this line:

`if less than 10 newobjs have been discovered over the last minute`

Comment: Don't have time to answer, but my answer would include two threads and a queue.  One thread to do the work and put results on the queue, another thread to watch and kill the first thread from executing if results come too slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough stab at it -- depending on the nature of `dig_more_objects` you may need to adjust the condition:

```
import time
results = []
while True:
    mark = time.time()
    newobjs = dig_more_objects(obj)
    elapsed = time.time() - mark
    results.append((newobjs, elapsed))
    count = 0
    threshhold = 0
    for objs, elapsed in results[::-1]:
        count += len(objs)  # or +1 of dig_more_objects only returns one at a time
        threshhold += elapsed
        if threshhold > 60.0 and count < 10:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to hold the times of the discovered objects, and if you pop a value that is less than one minute old and there are 9 or fewer items in the deque, break out of the loop. Don't forget to push it back in if there are more than 9 items though. Items older than a minute get discarded.

Comment: What if producing a single object takes thirty minutes?  Checking the deque won't happen quickly enough without threading.

Comment: True, but that's a problem-domain issue that no context has been given for. I'm assuming that `dig_more_objects()` is non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [multiton pattern](http://gen5.info/q/2008/07/25/the-multiton-design-pattern/) with a timer and design such a class. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern#Python) for an idea